# Metro styled Silverlight Applications

Tags: silverlight-4.0, expression-blend, silverlight-toolkit, windows-8, microsoft-metro

Is there any guidance available on developing Metro styled silverlight applications? How does one go about designing the UI to match the metro look and feel of WP7. Going by the way windows 8's UI & UX is, I assume the future of how we develop applications for the future versions of the win OS might be changing to look more or less 'metro'.

So what I am asking is, if anyone knows of any resource or has any ideas on how to use the currently available silverlight controls to achieve that look and feel. Is there anything planned to change the controls to match that UX out of the box and more natively?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you know Metro is not tied to any technology. You can reference WP7 UI guidelines to get some hints; a new version of the guideline is available from Microsoft web site.

For Silverlight 4, you can download themes from Microsoft http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=e9da0eb8-f31b-4490-85b8-92c2f807df9e

The Cosmopolitan theme when applied to a Silverlight4 application will give you Metro UI.

You can either apply the theme as-is or have a look in the xaml resource files to see how the theme is designed (brushes, fonts, styles etc)

For good UI (including Metro concepts and Blend) reference, I recommend visiting http://www.riagenic.com/

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Have you missed this session?
http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/BUILD/BUILD2011/TOOL-790C

It shows step-by-step how a WP7 (~Silverlight) application can be be turned into a Metro-style application. Although it doesn't go into design principles.

Edit: haha, missed to see that this question was asked months ago, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Infragistics have published a [free metro theme](http://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/blagunas/archive/2013/05/25/free-metro-light-and-dark-themes-for-wpf-and-silverlight-microsoft-controls.aspx) for Silverlight.